# Do aircraft technicians need additional certifications to work in other countries?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations, general-aviation, aircraft-maintenance

Professional technicians, who work in aircraft maintenance, usually obtain some sort of national certification, right?

Let's suppose someone got training and certification in one country, and wants to migrate to another country. Does he require some certification to work there as an aircraft technician? How is it achieved?

Comment: There are two parts to this question; one is the technical certification of the technician which has to match the regulations of the other country, the other part is about labour and migration laws. The latter part is out of scope here, the first part can only be answered if we know which countries you have in mind.

Comment: By 'migrate' I meant the migration of their technical certification to the target country, not the actual process of relocating. Really I just want to know if someone has gone through this or knows of someone who did, in any country combination.

Comment: In addition to what @DeltaLima said, `do you think it would be easy` is speculation, please think about removing or reformulating the question

Answer (score 5):

I don't have personal experience, but this is absolutely something you can do.

Unfortunately many countries do not have the exact same standards or licensing scheme, so often your licence is not automatically converted, but you rarely need to start from scratch.

For example, if you wanted to come to Australia, you would need to attend a CASA approved Part 147 training organisation, which are located around the world. They will assess you, possibly provide you with some extra training, following which you can apply for an Australian Part 66 engineer licence. Once you get that licence you shouldn't have too much difficulty migrating, but that's a discussion outside of my league. More details on this conversion process are on the [CASA website](http://casa.gov.au/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_90484).